# Levantando un proyecto de una pwa de vue con ngrok en docker Oo

Tags: docker, vue3, pwa

un cordial saludo a toda la comunidad de vue.
actualmente estoy probando el servicio de pwa de vue, levantandolo con ngrok, todo esto usando docker con una imagen de node 14.

el problema es que cuando ejecuto el ngrok funciona, pero a la hora de visitar el sitio da error el proyecto en vue, les dejo aca unos captures por si a alguien lo ha intentado y le funciono!.

A la espera de sus feedback, espero me puedan ayudar con este pequeño problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3]

Comment: como esta corriendo en un contenedor le redirigi el localhost a la ip del container ./ngrok http 172.17.0.2:8080, como el error cambio a "Invalid Host header" le mande el comando: ./ngrok http -host-header=rewrite 172.17.0.2:8080 con este se solucioneo ese mensaje, pero queda dando error de WebSocket

Comment: revisa bien las condiciones de ngrok pues hay cosas que se ven limitadas por el servicio por ejemplo que despues de una hora el servicio se corta, las nuevas versiones de vscode ya permiten hacer lo mismo que ngrok por ejemplo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12arVHVhB9g

Comment: @John gracias por tu feedback, la v3rsion que ocupo es la 2.3.41  
y sobre lo del video, no sale nada  jejeje